# Division errors in Pivot Table calculated items

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

I have a Pivot Table P&L with the following rows:
Income, COGS, Expenses, Other Income, Other Expenses.

Using calculated items, I have added Gross Profit and Net Profit. Those calculations work exactly as I want.

However, I run into two issues when I add in gross and net profit percentage calculated items.

Issue 1:
I get a #DIV/0! error on all the COGS and Expense amounts.

Issue 2:
All the Income amounts are counted instead of summed. They all show as "1".

These are the formulas:
'Gross Profit'/Income
'Net Profit'/Income

The dataset columns are:
Account, Account type (Income, Expense, etc), Amount, Date

I have tried using Sum(Income) to get Excel to sum instead of count. That didn't work.

Youtuber video suggested If(Income = 0,0,'Gross Profit'/Income) to get rid of the #DIV/0! error but that turned all the errors to 0. Likely a more specific solution to her data than mine, since the outcome was expected.

Below is an example of the type of data in the table.

| Account Type | Account | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Income | Sales | 11/1/2022 | 500 |
| Income | Service | 11/5/2022 | 1000 |
| Income | Sales | 11/15/2022 | 750 |
| Income | Service | 11/20/2022 | 800 |
| COGS | COGS | 11/1/2022 | 400 |
| COGS | COGS | 11/15/2022 | 500 |
| COS | COS | 11/30/2022 | 600 |
| COS | COS | 11/30/2022 | 500 |
| OPEX | Advertising | 11/30/2022 | 400 |
| OPEX | Rent | 11/1/2022 | 500 |

Comment: Can you add a small sample dataset together with expected results? Also, are you sure you meant Calculated Item, and not Calculated Field?

Comment: Thanks, Jos. I added a table of example data.

It is calculated items that I'm using, not fields. The PivotTable is then arranged vertically like a P&L to show months horizontally.

In the rows of the PivotTable, I have: 
"Account Type" and "Account"; 
Values is "Sum of Amount"; 
Columns is "Date"

I then used the calculated items with the following formulas:
Gross Profit = Income - 'COGS' - 'COS'
Net Profit = Gross Profit - OPEX

The total net profit is correct. However, the DIV#/0 error and count issue arises when I add the 'Gross Profit'/Income and 'Net Profit'/Income formulas.